# Как дать доступ докер контейнеру Outline в локальную сеть

Tags: docker, сеть, vpn, подсети, outline

Есть сервер ubuntu с выделенным белым айпи адресом вида 193.16.х.х и внутренним локальным айпишником из подсети 192.168.250.0 Поднимаю Outline на Ubuntu через стандартный скрипт установки с официального сайта. После этого без проблем могу подключаться к серверу по его белому айпи, но естественно доступа к ресурсам которые лежат в подсети 250.0 у меня нет. Как можно проще всего это реализовать?